# Unable to debug a single .c file in vscode

Tags: c, ubuntu, debugging, gcc, visual-studio-code

I think it should be 6 hours I`m dealing with this problem! Anyway, I want to build a single .c file in vscode in linux ubuntu 64bit. Here is my code(quadratic-equation.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double quadratic_equation(float a, float b, float c);

int main()
{
    float x, a, b, c;

    printf("Enter a: ");
    scanf("%f", &a);

    printf("Enter b: ");
    scanf("%f", &b);

    printf("Enter c: ");
    scanf("%f", &c);

    x = quadratic_equation(a, b, c);
    printf("form: ax%c + bx + c = 0:\n", 253);
    printf("x = %f", x);

    return 0;
}

double quadratic_equation(float a, float b, float c)
{
    float x;

    if(a == 0)
    {
        if(b == 0)
        {
            printf("a & b can not be both zero");
        }
        else
        {
            x = -c / b;
            return x;
        }
    }
    if((b * b - 4 * a * c ) == 0)
    {
        x = -b / (2 * a);
        return x;
    }

    x = (-b + sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / 2 * a;
    return x;
}
```

I have resolved all the problems in this code.
On the way to build, VSCode forced me to create 3 files, c_cpp_properties.json, launch.json, And tasks.json.
So, I copy paste them here:
My c_cpp_properties.json file:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "/usr/include",
                "/usr/local/include",
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

My launch.json file:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/quadratic-equation.c",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "build quadratic equation"
        }
    ]
}
```

My tasks.json file:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build quadratic equation",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-g", "quadratic-equation.c"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is what gdb --version outputs:

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.1-0ubuntu3) 8.1.0.20180409-git
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
```

I also tried adding makefile file which didnt help.(I actually didnt know how to configure it, But I searched a little and had some tries, Which didn`t help).
And finally, Here is the error I get when I press f5 (start debugging):

```
Unable to start debugging. Program path '/home/amirali/XPSC/test/c-cpp/quadratic-equation.c' is missing or invalid.

GDB failed with message: "/home/amirali/XPSC/test/c-cpp/quadratic-equation.c": not in executable format: File format not recognized

This may occur if the process's executable was changed after the process was started, such as when installing an update. Try re-launching the application or restarting the machine.
```

Really thanks for your help

Comment: I would guess this line: `"program": "${workspaceFolder}/quadratic-equation.c",` should point to the compiled executable rather than the source file.

Comment: You must call gdb with the executable, not with the source file.

Comment: @EugeneSh. How can I compile my code? This is actually my problem!

Comment: The problem you present is not about compiling, but about debugging.

Comment: @EugeneSh. So how can I compile my code in vscode?

Comment: Note: `if((b * b - 4 * a * c ) == 0)
    {
        x = -b / (2 * a);
        return x;
    }` seems like pointless code.  No need for it.  Yet a test `if((b * b - 4 * a * c ) < 0)` is needed to prevent `sqrt(some_negative)`.

Comment: "I have resolved all the problems in this code." - definitively not. You don't even check for errors. And why do you use a `double` function, but store the result in a `float`? Sidenote: enaboe all recommended warnings, your compiler should be crying.

Comment: Post would benefit with a clear question.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite [True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51882430/unable-to-debug-a-single-c-file-in-vscode#comment90717423_51882430), various issues remain about  correct functionality of `quadratic_equation()`, yet that is not the apparent question/concern here.

Comment: @chux: Most likely not, I agree. The problem is mentioned in the title, last word. It does not really make sense to use that nuke for this homework. Another possible problem, which is not the reason: Idk the vscode json format, but to me it seems the code is compiled as C++, not C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer.
Run `gcc -g -o {executableDesiredFileName} {yourFile}.c -lm` in the working folder and path "program" in launch.json to the executable file (`-lm` will try to include hadditional headers, and -o will rename the compiled program as the default is *a.out*).